# How to secure values in the reactjs production env

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, production

Why are all the contents of the .env file still readable in the view-source js file? Even though the app has been built with "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build" or maybe there is a suggestion to protect.env for production?

[img view-source js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30MGg.png)

I tried not using "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build" and using only "react-scripts build" it worked, but my react source files will be in the resources of the browser

Comment: There is no way to hide env variables in react build. They have to be there so the app can work

Comment: @Konrad then is there a good way to solve this problem?

Comment: You can have a backend application that actually makes the request to the API instead of your react app and use it as a proxy

Comment: @Konrad Yes it can, but in this case I want to request and send a request to the API that I have created. And to access the API, I set it using the API Key so I can request or send the request. What is the method you can use in this case?